# propagate virtualized Ethernet interface link status from qemu guest to host

Tags: qemu, virsh

Is it possible to propagate Ethernet interface link status from guest to host, i.e if one does `ip l set dev eth0 down` in guest, then something is triggered in host? `virsh domif-getlink <domain> <int>` or qemu log files do not show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No.

Most VMs have some kind of virtualised network interface (e.g. a virtio NIC) attached to one of the host's interfaces via a bridge or tunnel or similar.

It **is** possible to pass through direct access to a hardware device (e.g. PCI/PCI-e or USB) so that **only** the VM has access to it.  There are very few use-cases for doing this with a network interface - things like running the firewall on your DSL or Fibre or whatever upstream link on a VM.

But that's not the same as propagating changes to a VM's NIC back to the host.   Part of the process of setting up pass-through hardware is telling the host's kernel to just ignore that piece of hardware.  The host doesn't have any direct access to that hardware, it's dedicated to the VM.

If the VM is acting as a router/firewall with that NIC, the host would have to route some or all packets via the VM (so the VM would have to have a virtualised interface as well as the real interface).

(I had to do something like this once with a very expensive spectrum analyser that the faculty I worked for at the time (chemistry) had bought.  It had a network interface and software that only ran on a specific ancient version of Windows.  We didn't want to put ancient windows directly on the faculty's LAN so we ran Windows in a VM on Linux with KVM)

Comment: I agree with cas.  The answer is no because it's considered improper for the guest/VM to be able to talk to the host/hypervisor.  If you really wanted to do what you're describing I think you would have to setup some kind of polling mechanism (e.g. ping) where the host periodically checks if the guest's network is alive, and do something if the network is unresponsive.

Comment: I was hoping, that [qemu Monitor](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor) would show the guest link status, but looks like it doesn't. However, one is able to change the link status of a guest network adapter from there with `set_link` command.